# In ggplot2 my percent labels aren't laying correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: pic]
I'm trying label percentages on my 100% stacked bar charts (see image). I calculate the percentages in the first block below, and then run my ggplot.
Do you know what I'm doing wrong, why are my percentages displaying this way?

```
library(scales)
percentData = surveyds %>%
  group_by(qtext, X_Gender, response) %>% 
  summarise(N = n()) %>% 
  mutate(prop = N/sum(N))
percentData$prop = label_percent(accuracy = 1)(percentData$prop) #make percent from decimal

surveyds$responsef = factor(
  surveyds$response,
  levels = c("Poor","Fair","Good","Very good", "Excellent"),
  ordered = TRUE
) #Order bars

#Run visual
ggplot(data =subset(surveyds, !is.na(responsef)))+ #responsef is my response factored
  geom_bar(aes(x = X_Gender, fill = responsef), position = 'fill', width = 0.5)+
  facet_grid(rows = vars(qtext))+ #qtext is my question text
  coord_flip()+
  ylab('Proportion')+
  xlab('question')+
  ggtitle('Change')+
  geom_text(data = percentData, aes(y = N, label = prop, x = X_Gender),
            position=position_fill(vjust=0.5))
```

Comment: Please share a sample of `surveyds` using `dput(surveyds)` otherwise your issue can not be reproduced!

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I cannot share the data unfortunately, but I think I know the issue. The labels are flipped, starting from the top of my picture Males: 1% should be for Poor, 7% for Fair, 15% to Good etc. Do you know how to overlay them reversed? I tried  reverse = TRUE, that didn't fix it. 

geom_text(data = percentData, aes(y = N, label = prop, x = X_Gender),
            position=position_fill(vjust=1, reverse = TRUE))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Needed to add a fill argument to my geom_text.

```
geom_text(data = percentData, aes(fill = responsef, y = N, label = prop, x = X_Gender,),
            position=position_fill(vjust=0.5))
```